# not getting vertical scroll

Tags: html, css

i am not getting vertical scrollbar...
jsfiddle link -> http://jsfiddle.net/QNuzb/2/
css is

```
 /* Navigation  */
#nav-bar {position: fixed;top: 0;left: 0;z-index: 999;width: 100%;height: 45px;background: #F5F5F5;}
#nav {width: 800px;margin: 0 auto;height: 48px;text-align:center;}
#nav > li { display: inline-block;width: 15em;}
ul{list-style-type: none; display:inline-block;margin:0 auto; padding:0; position:relative;font-weight: bold; }
ul li{display:block;display:inline-block; position:relative;margin-right:5px;margin-left:5px}
ul li a{text-align: center;font-size: 18px;margin: 5px;padding: 8px;text-decoration: none; text-transform: capitalized;height: 35px; color:#222; font-size:18px; line-height:48px;}
ul li a:hover, ul li a.active{text-align:center;border-bottom:3px solid #800000; color:#800000}

/*  Tabs    */
.etabs { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
.tab { display: inline-block; zoom:1; *display:inline; background: #eee; border: solid 1px #999; border-bottom: none; -moz-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0; -webkit-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0; }
.tab a { font-size: 14px; line-height: 2em; display: block; padding: 0 10px; outline: none; }
.tab a:hover { text-decoration: underline; }
.tab.active { background: #fff; padding-top: 6px; position: relative; top: 1px; border-color: #666; }
.tab a.active { font-weight: bold; }
.tab-container .panel-container { background: #fff; border: solid #666 1px; padding: 10px; -moz-border-radius: 0 4px 4px 4px; -webkit-border-radius: 0 4px 4px 4px; }
```

Comment: Only thing I can suspect here is `overflow: hidden;`

Comment: @Sachin i am removed js problem was in css

Comment: @Mr.Alien i am not used overflow property !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the `position: fixed;` in your nav-bar class. remove it.

```
#nav-bar {
position: fixed; /* remove */
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 999;
width: 100%;
height: 45px;
background: #F5F5F5;
}
```

Comment: @Nilay If answers help you, than you can reward the owner with a green tick besides his answer, this will also help future visitors to refer, also, you can upvote the answers when you get the rights to do so :)

Comment: and oh btw forgot to upvote so here it goes, the fiddle scared me because of the size of the JS